# run is not a git command

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, github-pages

I've been uploading and deploying my react app to the gh-pages branch using the command `git run deploy` and for some reason, when I use it again, I get an error saying that run is not a command when it used to recognise it, and now I can no longer update the live website. Anyone know what to do?

I haven't removed anything or added or installed anything. It was shortly after I pushed the latest to github. So I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

use `npm run deploy` instead of `git run deploy`